# Pass an array to a void function, and recursively print the elements

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm self teaching myself to program from a book. The task at hand is that I have to put an array with two subscripts through a function that returns nothing (a void function I assume), and recursively print each of the elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

void printArray (int source, int a, int b){
    if (a < b){
        cout << source[a] << " ";
        printArray(source, a + 1, b);
        }
}

int main (){
    const array<int, 10> theSource = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int al = 0;
    int bl = theSource.size();

    printArray(theSource, al, bl);
}
```

When I attempt to do this I get two errors.

```
11|error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript|
22|error: cannot convert 'const std::array<int, 10u>' to 'int' for argument '1' to 'void printArray(int, int, int)'|
```

So I tried changing the void to...

```
void printArray (int source[], int a, int b)
```

and also...

```
void printArray (int *source, int a, int b){
```

But still get the error...

```
22|error: cannot convert 'const std::array<int, 10u>' to 'int' for argument '1' to 'void printArray(int, int, int)'|
```

Is there a different way to put arrays through a function?

The task is...

> (Print an array) Write a recursive function printArray that takes an array, a starting sub-script and an ending subscript as arguments, returns nothing and prints the array. The function should stop processing and return when the starting subscript equals the ending subscript.

Comment: You could also use a template to deduce the array bounds. It's possible for std::array and c style arrays. Maybe a little more advanced than your assignment but safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the signature to:

```
void printArray (const array<int, 10> &source, int a, int b)
```

This is what compiler wants! :)

Comment: Oh wow that worked. Thank you very much. Sorry if it seemed like a dumb question. I'll mark this as correct when the timer lets me.

Comment: this works, but the array you've defined only has 9 values so it prints out a 0 for the 10th element

Comment: Heh, the values didn't really matter I think. With the array initializing undefined elements to 0, I just hastily put some numbers in there so that I wouldn't just see 0 over and over again.

Comment: @Greg You should also add bounds checking in the function. What happens when you pass negative values or values greater than 9 for `a` or `b`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer That's a great point. I'll super charge the program to make it a bit more robust, and keep an eye on including that in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're tangling up `std::array` with C-style "array". If you change the definition of `theSource` to

```
const int theSource[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

then either of the last two forms will work (provided you fix the constness, which the compiler will complain about), because `theArray` has type array of const int, and that can be passed to a function that's looking for `const int*`.

When someone uses arrays as an exercise in recursion that's almost certainly what they're looking for.

Of course, for **real** C++, `std::array<int, 10> theArray` is more appropriate, and should be passed to a function expecting `const std::array<int, 10>&` as its first argument.

Comment: Thank you. That is valuable advice, and I'll incorporate it. I know that const makes it so that it stays constant, which makes sense when passing the array to a function. It's a shame I spent so much time on this, since the book didn't really give me a good answer for this chapter.